# Typescrpt: foreach loop over string array to add new keys to given assosiative array

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have an array of strings

```
const firstArray = ["KeyOne", "KeyTwo", "KeyThree"]
```

and i want to use this array to create new keys for another (assosiative) array, like this:

```
secondArray = {};
secondArray["InitialKey"] = true
firstArray.forEach(function(value) {secondArray[value] = false});
```

But this way only the "InitialKey" gets added, none of the other keys. Whats wrong here?

edit: as mentioned in my comment, this works:

```
firstArray.forEach(value => {secondArray[value] = false})
```

yes the code is different and I am a typescript beginner but I do not understand why that makes such a difference.

Comment: Are you concerned about the types or the result of the `secondArray`? Because [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgSwE7QIJKQQwJ4wLwwDaARANICm2A8mOcQDQxmUAqA7iA0xdiwBZJydALoAoUQBtysCOVBgAJuizYAXDABKckEgUAeaEgRgA5o0xhsAPnwwA3gF8A3KNnylGHCQCSYBFARMCR5iYVsoJABXclFEFChlHAA6OB0AUUxgPgAKOEiwYADwbIA3IOiASns3cA8VQjKJaLCCOCDZBwqnGHFxeQgQKSSJEBNsmsVE7AqgA) all keys are added

Comment: I do not understand what the reason is, apart from that the code is different, but this works firstArray.forEach(value => {secondArray[value] = false})